# How to Fill Specific Cell in a Column Using Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

On my $A:$A, I currently have a dropdown list of "Yes" and "No".

For Example:

```
A1 = Yes then Fill B1 with black
A7 = No  then Fill B7 with Green

If Yes then Black
If No  then Green
```

I know that formula below can be used in a specific cell only. How can we add a conditional formatting in an entire column B based on the the value of the cell in Column A?

```
=$A$1 <> "Yes"   -> B1 Conditional formatting
```

Comment: Make the row on the formula relative by removing the $. Then apply it to all of the cells in column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much have it.

[image]

1. Select column B
2. Add a conditional formatting rule
3. Select "Use a formula to determine which cell to format"
4. Enter:
   =A1 <> "Yes"
   Note that it does *not* include the "$" before the "1".  Omitting the "$" makes the reference relative, so it'll fill down much like a formula in the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: Thanks for this it worked :D However, when no selection was made, how can we default this as no fill? For example, in cell A7, there's no current value assigned but the cell B7 was filled with black.

Comment: @PeterS Glad it worked for you! For that, I'd change the formula to:   
=A1="No"

Comment: My only problem with this one is how about the cell without selection? How can I default them with no fill? For example A2 was blank, how can I default the B2 cell to be no fill?

Comment: If you set the conditional formatting formula to =A1="No", it will only fill if the A cell is exactly "No".  Blanks, "Yes", or anything else will have no fill.